# Slider not Working after converting to angular

Tags: angular

I was trying to create a portfolio on angular. But the slider part is not working in angular. It is working correctly on the normal HTML code. I am beginner and I am trying hard to learn it.

Since the code is large i. uploaded it to my git. Please find the below link.

https://github.com/sarathhari7/updatedportfolio.git

```
        "scripts": [
        "src/assets/js/vendor.js",
        "src/assets/js/custom.js"
      ]
```

[image]

Comment: There is no package.json in your github. post complete project please.

Comment: did you include your script in app.modules?

Comment: @AakashGarg Code updated. I didn't add a node_module folder since its too big. it's not allowing me to upload

Comment: @RomanHDev No I didn't. I included it in the angular.json since its an external script code.

Comment: @SarathHari it's been a while since I used angular the last time, but as far as I am aware you need to import everything you'd wish to use inside of your angular project into you app.components.ts file and include it in the import array to make angular aware of its existence

Comment: what is index-13.html# ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed your testimonial slider.

Couple of issues found :-

1. With slider buttons you were using href, routerlink to be used.
2. Install slider in you project using npm i slider --save
3. Install @types/slider in your project using npm i @types/swiper --save-dev,
4. your changed home.component.ts below :-

> ```
> import { Component, OnInit, AfterViewInit } from '@angular/core';
> import Swiper from 'swiper/';
> @Component({
>   selector: 'app-home',
>   templateUrl: './home.component.html',
>   styleUrls: ['./home.component.css','../app.component.css'],
> })
> export class HomeComponent implements OnInit, AfterViewInit {
>   public swiper;
>   name = "Sarath Hari";
>   services : any;
>   constructor() { 
>     this.services =
>       [
>         {
>           service_name:"Web Development",
>           desc:"Working with the skill set of HTML5, CSS3, jQuery, Bootstrap, PHP & Angualr",
>           image:"website.jpg"
>         },
>         {
>           service_name:"Graphic Design",
>           desc:"Creates attractive Banners, Logos and Info graphics for all kind of events and business",
>           image:"logo.jpg"
>         },
>         {
>           service_name:"Video Animations",
>           desc:"Using After Effects to create beautiful Logo, App  presentations and explanatory videos",
>           image:"video.jpg"
>         },
>         {
>           service_name:"Photography",
>           desc:"Captures your most beautiful evens, portraits, products etc . . .",
>           image:"photography.jpg"
>         },
>         {
>           service_name:"SEO / SEM",
>           desc:"Help you boost your business through the advertising platforms like google, facebook etc",
>           image:"seo-sem.jpg"
>         },
>         {
>           service_name:"Web Hosting",
>           desc:"Host your website on any top servers and never let it go down.",
>           image:"hosting.jpg"
>         }       
>       ]
>
>   }
>
>   ngOnInit() {
>
>   }
>
>   ngAfterViewInit() {
>     this.swiper = new Swiper('.swiper-testimony', {
>       spaceBetween: 30,
>       navigation: {
>           nextEl: '.swiper-button-next',
>           prevEl: '.swiper-button-prev',
>       },
>    });
>   }
>
> }
> ```

5. HTML router link change for your reference :-

> ```
> <a [routerLink]="" class="swiper-button-next"></a>
> <a [routerLink]="" class="swiper-button-prev"></a>
> ```

6. you don't need custom.js and vendor.js anymore.

Comment: Thank you soo much bro. The router I didn't use since I am going to learn it. But still, no idea how you installed the sliders. Can I get connected to you if I get any doubts?. I ill vote as soon as I check it

Comment: I have sent you pull request in your repository. You can see the changes. Please vote my answer if its correct.After taking update, run npm install.

Comment: How to check the pull request. I am not getting any requests.

Comment: I am getting error ERROR in src/app/home/home.component.ts:2:20 - error TS2307: Cannot find module 'swiper/'.

Comment: run "npm install" in your project before running it

Comment: can we connect over webex?

Comment: how can we connect?

Comment: Yes we can connect in Webex or Microsoft team

Comment: I updated my question with the screenshot. Please check

Comment: I fixed it. My mistake I installed swiper inside app folder